# Verificar hash para logear

Tags: php, mysql

```js
<?php
  $servidor="localhost";
  $nombreBd="carrito";
  $usuario="root";
  $pass="";
  $conexion = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$pass,$nombreBd);
  if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("No se pudo conectar");
  }


 ?>
```

Estoy haciendo un login, pero no entiendo como hacer la comparación del hash que está en la base de datos y la password que ingresa el usuario. Se que esta comparación se realiza con: password_verify, he leido distintas páginas que hablan sobre esto pero no entiendo bien, vi este vídeo(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfOxyQcbawc) que era algo parecido, pero me perdí y no entiendo. Si me pueden ayudar agradecería.

```js
<?php
include'php/conexion.php';

$usuario=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$password=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$hash="";
$sql= "SELECT email, password FROM usuario WHERE email='$usuario' AND password='$password'" ;
$resultado= $conexion->query($sql);
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
  echo "está bien";
}else{
  echo "algo falló";
}
// if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {
//   echo "Bienvenido";
// }else {
//   echo "algo falló";
// }



 ?>
```

Comment: Tu duda no se entiende, ¿este código funciona? o preguntas como funciona la comparación¿?

Comment: Pregunto más bien cómo se comparan las dos cosas. ¿Debo almacenar el hash que está en la base de datos en una variable en php y comprar esa variable con la variable que contiene la password que el usuario ingresó?, de ser así como almaceno el hash de la base de datos en una variable.

Comment: Es simple: A. Para el INSERT tomas el POST, haces el hash y guardas ese hash. B. Para el LOGIN recuperas la columna password del SELECT (es lo que te falta por hacer) y la comparas con el dato que ingresó el usuario mediante password_verify. Revisa [esta nota del Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php#121974) que explica de modo sencillo lo que hay que hacer.

Comment: @Liz, si miras el video nuevamente, a partir del minuto [`9:00`](https://youtu.be/XfOxyQcbawc?t=540) vas a encontrar el código correcto.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cual es el problema con mi login.php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/362200/cual-es-el-problema-con-mi-login-php)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [validacion con password\_verify](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/360919/validacion-con-password-verify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la parte del Login hay que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Recoger la clave que haya escrito el usuario (en este caso sería el valor de `$password`).
2. Recoger el valor de la columna `password` de la base de datos, que estarías recuperando en el `SELECT` (eso es lo que te está faltando).
3. Comparar ambos valores mediante `password_verify()`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$resultado=$conexion->query($sql);
$fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
$hashedPwd=$fila["password"];
$msg=(password_verify($password, $hashedPwd)) ? "Todo bien" : "Algo falló";
echo $msg;
```

Otra cosa **muy importante** es que, para que todo esto funcione, debiste haber usado [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) cuando hiciste el `INSERT` de la clave en la base de datos.